# How to make image center vertically in Jquery Mobile ListView Control?

Tags: jquery, html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I have following html,

http://jsfiddle.net/2bWfL/168/

```
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>

        <a href="#">
            <img width="80" height"80" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7efa2e4098f60c15d230436ca99d7250?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />
            <h3>New Latest One</h3>
            <p>$12,000</p>
        <input type="text" style="width:75px"/>
            </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
<style>
        .ui-input-text{
            width: 75px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

But image is not in center vertically. How to make it center?

Comment: Did you meant vertically, there's no point in centering it horizontally?

Comment: @Gajotres, corrrect. I have updated question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you want to vertical align your image. If so, you just need to apply this css to your image:

```
img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yWkGR/

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the input to right instead of bottom?

Comment: You just need to apply float, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yWkGR/1/. If you don't understand, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/XawBx/

Used css:

```
#test {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    height:80px; 
    width:80px;       
}
```

## Final notes

If you want to find more about how to customize jQuery Mobile page and widgets then take a look at this [article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/). It comes with a lot of working examples, including why is !important necessary for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: This is also same as above Thanks